# WCF process and non-wcf process, main 3 components of WCF, code name for WCF

Tags: wcf

I have a few question on WCF, as below:

1 What are the main 3 components of WCF?

2 When a WCF process connects with a non-WCF process it uses ***_*__*_*__** based encoding for SOAP messages.

3 What was the code name for WCF?

Any idea would be very much appriecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you've been asked these question in interview! please find the answers,

```
1 What are the main 3 components of WCF?
RE: a) Address, b) Binding c) Contract

2 When a WCF process connects with a non-WCF process it uses ______ based encoding for SOAP messages.
RE: By default it uses TextMessageEncoding

3 What was the code name for WCF? 
RE: Indigo
```